# Class 'Pitchanon\FacebookConnect\FacebookConnectServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel4 framework, i am getting this error:

```
Class 'Pitchanon\FacebookConnect\FacebookConnectServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: What code are you using that leads to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Open up app/config/app.php and add this string to providers array.

```
    'Pitchanon\FacebookConnect\FacebookConnectServiceProvider'
```

Then execute `composer dump-autoload`.